# UICollectionView gets stuck while loading facebook videos URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, video

I have fetched facebook photos and videos through facebook SDK and loaded it into a UICollectionView.I have Used SDWebImage for Caching images .Is there a way to cache videos because while scrolling UICollectionView when there is an array of videos ,it gets stuck while scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Do not cache the videos, display only thumbnail image of the video from the response.

see this response link of Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video-thumbnail/